# how to code Smooth axis rotation of one object via mouse using the three js Editor

Tags: three.js

how to code Smooth axis rotation of one object via mouse using the three js Editor

here the example but it will be better avoid the click

http://benchung.com/smooth-mouse-rotation-three-js/

Comment: @jscastro Hi, I reformulated the question

Comment: The controls of the `three.js` editor do not support damping. Consider to create custom a fork and replace `EditorControls` with `OrbitControls`.